# Unexpected changes of the width attribute of a component

Tags: java, swing

I have noticed that running the program I'm listing below sometimes produces an unwanted effect.

**EDIT: I've simplified the code to make things look clear. I'm drawing a String which prints out the current component size. I've overriden the getPrefferedSize() method in the Component class and set width and height to 640 x 512 respectively. However, I'm still getting different results after running the program: 640 x 512 and 650 x 522. Weird thing is removing the frame.setResizable(false) line fixes things. But I want the window to be resizable**

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                DrawFrame frame = new DrawFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}


class DrawFrame extends JFrame
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public DrawFrame()
    {
        setTitle("DrawTest");
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        DrawComponent component = new DrawComponent();
        contentPane.add(component);
    }

}

class DrawComponent extends JComponent
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(640, 512);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;         
        String msg = getWidth() + " x " + getHeight();      
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        g2.drawString(msg, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Best guess for the behavior I can think of is, that you using `setPreferredSize()` for the `Content Pane`. Instead of this what you can do is override the [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize()), and make it return a value that you wanted to set as a Preferred Size for the `JComponent`. one example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230), [another here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11534873/1057230), [and one More here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11376322/1057230)

Comment: As to why this approach is beneficial, have a look at this [wonderful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11377526/1057230) by @trashgod

Comment: Thanks for hints. I've overriden the method as you pointed out, and simplified the code. However problem still appears and I have no idea why. Check the edit in OP.

Comment: You are MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-) I did noticed, running the program several times did gives you `650 X 522` which is not expected. Seems like that `frame.setResizable(...)` is at fault, though I am using `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)` on Windoes 7 32-bit Platform, Hope it's not another bug of 1.7 :(

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `setLocationByPlatform()` must follow `pack()` and precede `setVisible()`, or the geometry will be wrong. Absent a reason to subclass `JFrame`, I have elided `DrawFrame` is the example below. Note the use of `FontMetrics` to keep the text centered as the enclosing container is resized. The approach is handy for learning layouts.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawTest");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new DrawComponent());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class DrawComponent extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(320, 240);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        String msg = getWidth() + " x " + getHeight();
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        int w = (getWidth() - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(msg)) / 2;
        g2.drawString(msg, w, getHeight() / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I can't thank enough for your time. But try to add frame.setResizable(false) to your code and the "+10px bug" is still appearing. I put setResizable line before pack(), assuming that should be correct.

Comment: I can't reproduce the effect you describe using `setResizable(false)` before `pack()`, but the frame decorations vary by platform. What host OS?

Comment: @trashgod : I had tried this sequence, putting `setResizable(...)` as the first line, after setting default CLOSE Behavior, then added components to the `JFrame` then `pack()` then `Location` and then `setVisible()` , though still after seven or eight tries, this size issue pops up :(

Comment: @nIcEcOw: Thank you for reporting this result. I am unable to reproduce the effect on Mac OS X or Ubuntu using Java 1.6. I'm guessing the Windows frame resize decorations are the culprit.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe because native windowing system may ignore such requests like set frame size. 
setSize() method have similar problem:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29

> "The method changes the geometry-related data. Therefore, the native
>   windowing system may ignore such requests, or it may modify the
>   requested data, so that the Window object is placed and sized in a way
>   that corresponds closely to the desktop settings."

Simple test, try:

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(2000, 1000);
}
```

similar settings probably will be ignore.

check also this topic: [setSize() doesn't work for JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536804/setsize-doesnt-work-for-jframe)